# How to get a local date-time from a time_t with boost::date_time?

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, boost-date-time

I'm using boost::date_time and I got a time_t, that have been generated by a library using the time() function from the C standard library.

I'm looking for a way get a local time from that time_t. I'm reading the documentation and can't find any way to do this without providing a time zone, that I don't know about because it's dependant on the machine's locale, and I can't find any way to get one from it.

What am I missing?

Comment: I take it you can't change the library, so you're stuck with `time()`?

Comment: Exactly. I would have used the boost-given local time and no time_t if I could. But cannot :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task, I'd ignore `boost::date_time` and just use [`localtime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) (or `localtime_r`, if available) from the standard library.

Comment: Ok so I used this and built a boost::posix_time::ptime with it to manipulate the time once localized. Thanks it works!

Comment: Aren't boost date/time objects supposed to be thread-safe ? Localtime isn't really an alternative in that case.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, thread safety would be one of the reasons to use "`localtime_r`, if available".

Answer (score 13):

[boost::posix_time::from_time_t()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_struct_tm)

```
#include <ctime>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time_adjustor.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/c_local_time_adjustor.hpp>

boost::posix_time::ptime local_ptime_from_utc_time_t(std::time_t const t)
{
    using boost::date_time::c_local_adjustor;
    using boost::posix_time::from_time_t;
    using boost::posix_time::ptime;
    return c_local_adjustor<ptime>::utc_to_local(from_time_t(t));
}

int main()
{
    using boost::posix_time::to_simple_string;
    using boost::posix_time::from_time_t;

    std::time_t t;
    std::time(&t); // initalize t as appropriate
    std::cout
        << "utc:   "
        << to_simple_string(from_time_t(t))
        << "\nlocal: "
        << to_simple_string(local_ptime_from_utc_time_t(t))
        << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: -1 : I said a LOCAL time. I'm already using this and it's wrong because it don't take account of the locale time. For example, I'm in GMT+2, so when I do time() it gives me GMT+0 and I have to add two hours to get the corret time. I don't even know where will be the user of the app and need to take the local time.

Comment: @Klaim : Edited to demonstrate a complete example (I figured converting from utc to local was the obvious part and you didn't know how to get a `ptime` from a `std::time_t`).