# How to initialize and allocate memory for an array in a struct in header file?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, new-operator

My question is like this, there is a `struct data` in `test.h`

```
struct data {
static int year[10];
static int month[12];
static int day[31];
};
```

In Cpp file, I have several functions which need to call it. Where and how should I initialize it?

```
void test::display(){
     struct data pointer;
     /* ... */
     // These three arrays should be initialized
     pointer.year[index1] = Timeyear;
     pointer.month[index2] = Timemonth;
     pointer.day[index3] = Timeday;
     printf("%d %d %d", pointer.year[index1],
         pointer.month[index2], pointer.day[index3]);
     /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by the name `pointer` -- are you actually passing around a _pointer_ to a block of memory of type `struct data` or is that just the first name that came to mind?

Comment: first of all, using 31 ints to store a day seems like an awful waste of space. second of all, if this is C++, you can just initialize them in a constructor.

Comment: `pointer` is decidedly not a pointer.

Comment: @sarnold Sorry for that. It is just a name, the name of struct object.

Comment: @Daniel Could you please give some details? I try to do it in constructor, but not successful.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be very confused between C and C++.

`printf`? It's bad. Really bad. `struct data pointer`? Ditch the `struct`.

Also, if you want to initialize it, just *use a constructor*.

Comment: I put "int data::year[] = 0;" into the constructor, but it has an error "invalid use of qualified-name ‘data::year’" when compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has already been taken care of by the STL.

You should learn more about std::time_t objects

See also:

[String representation of time_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997512/string-representation-of-time-t)

[How to get a local date-time from a time_t with boost::date_time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143569/how-to-get-a-local-date-time-from-a-time-t-with-boostdate-time)

[time_t conversion format question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582263/time-t-conversion-format-question)